# Using bit with int in structure

Tags: c, struct

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   struct a
   {
      int a:4;
   };
   main(){
   struct a aa;
   aa.a=9;
   printf("a=%d\n",aa.a);
   return 0;
   }
```

Here the output is -7. Why is it so?
what does exactly int a:4 does ? please explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), the highest order bit is used for the sign.  By writing `a:4` you're saying to only allocate 4 bits of memory, which leaves 3 bits left over for the actual number.  So our effective range is `[-8,7]`. Since all 1's is -1, there's an extra number on the negative side. For more of an explanation on this, see the above link.

9, in (unsigned) binary is: `1001`.  When you put this into `a` (signed), you get that `a` is negative, due to the initial 1, and since the following numbers are `001`, we add 1 to the max negative number, thereby giving us -7.

If you want to store the number 9 in only 4 bits, you need to use an `unsigned int`, which would give you a range of `[0, 15]`.

**EDIT:**
In case anyone is struggling with figuring out how `1001` signed gives us -7, consider the following:

Since `1111` is -1, let some variable `value = -1`.

To figure out the values of a negative (signed) `int num`, let us denote x<sub>i</sub> in `num`:

x<sub>i</sub> : {0,1 at position i, where i=0 is the least significant bit)},

Then, for every x<sub>i</sub> = 0, subtract 2<sup>i</sup> from `value`.

Example:

`1001`:

`value` = -1 - 2<sup>1</sup> - 2<sup>2</sup> = -7

Comment: The `int` in a bitfield might be `unsigned int` by default.  It appears not to be in the OP's case, but it never hurts to read the documentation.

Comment: Nice question and very nice answer! I verified that the unsigned type will give the expected answer.

Comment: I prefer to think of the MSB as having the value -2^3 + 2^0 -- that way all the non-MSBs have their usual value.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I was thinking about it above the edit, but I wanted to show an alternative too.

Answer (score 4):

Your field is a 4 bit signed integer.  For signed integers the upper bit is a sign bit, which means that you only have 3 bits for the actual number.  The range of numbers you can store in the field are -8 to 7 (assuming 2's compliment storage).

The bit pattern for 9 is 1001, which has the 4th bit set, meaning it is interpreted as a negative number, which is why it is printing out as a -7.  If you would have expected a -1, you need to read up on [2's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

If you want to be able to store 9 in the field, make `a` an `unsigned int`

Answer (score 3):

You only reserved 4 bits for the field, one bit is used for the sign, so only 3 bits remain for positive values. Thus you can only store values up to 7.

Comment: could u please explain using binary representation?

Answer (score 2):

you have to use **unsigned** indeed **int** :

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct a
{
  unsigned a:4; //  <-- unsigned indeed int, then work good
};
main(){
struct a aa;
aa.a=9;
printf("a=%d\n",aa.a);
return 0;
}
```

output :

```
   a=9
```